# URL shortening in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

**REVISED QUESTION**
1. I create a post, and after putting the title, I get something like this:

"http://mysite.com/category/post-name-which-is-quite-long"

Once I save draft copy, I get the box "Get shortlink" containing something like "http://wp.me/xxyyxx34 ..." If I click OK nothing happens. If I click on Edit button, only the post-name can be edited, not the earlier part.

What I want to know is: can some utility provide me the FULL url shortened and acceptable by wordpress? That is, instead of:

"http://mysite.com/category/post-name-which-is-quite-long"

can I get something like this:

"http://short-url.com/xyzz ?"

Also, if indeed this is possible, will wordpress accept it as the post-title-url?

Hope I am able to ask my question!

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. What URL shortener have you used, what was the output, and what was the output that you are looking for.

Comment: URL shortening is not a Wordpress feature. You might be using a plugin, and/or your question needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the *Get shortlink* button, the popup window contains a wp.me link, which is a working shortened URL, see usage [here](http://jetpack.me/support/wp-me-shortlinks/).

(Short URLs are a [built-in feature](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/shorten/) on wordpress.com and the free [WordPress Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/support/wp-me-shortlinks/) plugin also adds this functionality.)